# How to upgrade the quality of a Blob image after SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, image-processing, blob

The Encode source i have to put these Blobs (images) in my database is

```
Bitmap image15 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.wolverineklein);

// convert bitmap to byte
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image15.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte imageInByte1[] = stream.toByteArray();
```

And this is the code to get the image back from the SQLite database

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(camera.this);
List<Database> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
for (Database contact : contacts) {
BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmpFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
//bmpFactoryOptions.inScaled = false;
// decodes the blob back into a bitmap
byte[] blob = contact.getMP();
 ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
Bitmap scalen = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 320, 240, false);
```

The code works fine, but the output of the images is of a lower quality (the difference isn't that big, but i use it for feature matching so it does impact the results. The right output image is more blurry then the )
[image][image]

As you can see, the right image is the output and it is more bit-like (check out the upper chest area and compare it to the left input image) then the original + the size is bigger. Is there a possibility to make the quality better then I have it right now?

Comment: What happens when you leave off the final scaling step?  'Cos my reading of the code and the APIs is that *that* is where the blurring is likely to be happening.

Comment: If I do this, my output image is larger than the original one, and I want them both to be the same size. I don't think I'm using the BitmapFactory.Options like it should, because when i place       `bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight = 240;
bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth = 320;` in the code, the output image is still larger. So that's why I added the scaling.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that saving an image (compressed or otherwise) to a database and bringing it back will change its size.

Comment: It does for some reason (has something to do with the reconstruction and the dpi that your phone has, it's reconstructed based on the dpi of your phone) but can be solved my using `bmpFactoryOptions.inScaled = false;` , but the options don't work for me.

Comment: Well perhaps there is an explanation for why the didn't work.  In the code in your example, you don't **use** the bitmapfactoryoptions that you are creating.

Comment: yes, i fixed the problem ;) should close this tbh